# Need Help in django form widgets

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am in a middle of a project. I need help in using widgets. I have a Model for which i want a model form :
My model is :

```
    class Appointments(models.Model):
      doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      app_time = models.DateTimeField()
      diognoses = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
      prescriptions = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('doctor', 'patient', 'app_time')

    def __str__(self):
        st = str(self.patient.user.name)+str(self.doctor.user.name)
        return st
```

The corresponding model form is :

```
        class AppointmentBookForm(forms.ModelForm):
            app_time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.SplitDateTimeWidget())

        class Meta:
            model = Appointments
            fields = ['doctor','app_time']
```

Now for app_time I have split the date and time field which is already working fine.
Now I want a dropdown for date and a suitable widget for time.
The time should contain only hours and minutes.
And Finally I also want to provide the options for timing depending on the date and doctor.

Comment: Are you using any particular frameworks on the frontend?  I think the current widgets just use the built-in functionality of the browser.

Comment: No I am using plane HTML. But i previously used dropdowns for date field.

Answer (score 0):

For plain html the easiest way might be to define two input fields, one for the time and one for the date.

Input type="date":
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp

Input type="time":
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_time.asp

There are multiple results to this, here is one proposal:

**models.py**

```
from datetime import datetime

class Appointments(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.TimeField()
    date = models.DateField()
    app_time = models.DateTimeField()
    diognoses = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    prescriptions = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.app_time = datetime.combine(self.date, self.time)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('doctor', 'patient', 'app_time')

    def __str__(self):
        st = str(self.patient.user.name)+str(self.doctor.user.name)
        return st
```

**forms.py**

```
class AppointmentBookForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Appointments
        fields = ['doctor', 'time', 'date']
        """
        # Optional: Define dedicated types or classes for the single fields
        widgets = {
            'time': forms.DateField(attr={"class": "myclass", "type": "time"})
        }
        """
```

The app_time is quite redundant in this case. You could also define a property to receive the datetime:

```
class Appointments(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.TimeField()
    date = models.DateField()
    diognoses = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    prescriptions = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def app_time(self):
        return datetime.combine(date, time)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('doctor', 'patient', 'time', 'date')

    def __str__(self):
        st = str(self.patient.user.name)+str(self.doctor.user.name)
        return st
```

example:

```
appointment = Appointments.objects.first()
print(appointment.app_time)
```

Alternatively, use some nice front end framework if you want to keep a single datetimefield.